# Переписать SQL запрос через Django ORM

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-orm

Как преобразовать sql запрос со связанными таблицами в django orm.
Сам sql запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM `main_people`
WHERE `status_id` in (
    SELECT id FROM `main_peoplestatus` WHERE opisan_stat LIKE '%действующий%'
)
```

Посмотрел джанго ORM запросы, но не получилось со связанных таблиц вывести.

Comment: Добавьте код моделей, если хотите больше помощи, тк вы предоставили мало информации.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
People.objects.filter(status__opisan_stat__contains='действующий')
```

Comment: Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. Кнопка «Отправить ответ» только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы.

Comment: Сам ответ можно оставить, так как он может оказаться полезным автору и другим пользователям. А комментарии-уточнения все-таки лучше писать в комментариях.

Comment: Вынес обращение к автору в комментарий

Comment: Спасибо большое !получилось только по id

Comment: если получилось только по `id` значит что то не так написали