# Как сделать SQL запрос в Джанго?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Мне необходимо выполнить запрос вида

```
DELETE FROM django_migrations WHERE app='название_приложения';
```

для очистки от миграций таблицы django_migrations. Но как это сделать в Django?

================================

Пока только так смог. А в Django возможно?

В SQLiteStudio открыл окно запросов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и там прописал свой запрос, после выполнил

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ответ дан в другом вопросе
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1312506/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-sql-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-django-orm?rq=1

Comment: @AleksandrFetisov в этом вопросе он никак не поможет

Answer (score 0):

Пользуюсь самописной функцией во всех своих проектах:

```
def sql (req, returnid = False):
    import sqlite3 as sqlite
    connection = sqlite.connect('db.sqlite3') # Название БД рядом с файликом manage.py
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute (str (req))
    connection.commit()
    if returnid == False:
        rows = cursor.fetchall ()
    else:
        rows = cursor.lastrowid
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
    return rows
```

Вызывается просто:

```
sql ("DELETE FROM django_migrations WHERE app='название_приложения'")
```

Первый аргументом передаете сам SQL-запрос и если есть что вернуть, то функция вернет (для SELECT, например). Вторым аргументом можно передать значение True и тогда функция вернет id новой записи (для INSERT).